# Testing PhoneGap+AJAX apps in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cordova

I have been using Cordova/PhoneGap for some time and until now, I used Chrome to try out the application in a browser.

The app had lots of AJAX petitions to a different server, so I used Chrome's --disable-web-security argument to allow for these. However, this argument seems not to work any longer: new versions of Chrome complain that this argument is not allowed. I've tried this on Chromium and I get the same error message either. Furthermore, I have tried setting Firefox's security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false to see if I could get it to work there, to no avail.

Do you know how to test such an app in a modern browser? If not, is there a way to fall back to a previous version of Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). You can activate/deactivate CORS with one click :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I get the following error in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Projects/myproject/www/app/i18n/de.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: I think it's because you're getting this json from a local file system. Try to put this on a local server (localhost). You can do it with a apache server.
Will be like http://localhost/app/i18n/de.json

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working now. However, if the request has the Content-Type header, it fails. Right now I have removed this header from my requests, which is better than nothing, but this is a temporary solution at best. Any other approach which would involve less boilerplate (e.g. having a web server and changing the code) would be much appreciated.