# How do I deploy Cordova WebApplication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, reactjs

I made WebApplication by Cordova + React
I could run on local env(localhost:8000).
but I don't know the way to deploy.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app on browser",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "author": "maki",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "history": "^4.2.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^2.2.3",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-motion": "^0.4.4",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.7.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.13.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

this is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AI & Society Lab</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

file structure in /WWW/

```
index.html
----js
--------dist.js
----jsx
--------[pages files]
--------[components files]
----sass
--------[scss files]
----img
--------[images]
```

How do I deploy Cordova WebApplication to deploy to server?
please help me!!

Comment: Cordova applications are designed to be run on mobile devices, not as a web application on a server.

Comment: read this: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing PhoneGap+AJAX apps in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043787/testing-phonegapajax-apps-in-browser)